# creating venv with python3.9 causes error

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm relatively new with Python and I have been creating virtual environments for my different projects.
If I use the following command:

```
python3 -m venv <name_of_env>
```

this works and creates a virtual environment with python 3.8.5

However if I try the same command using -> python3.9 -m venv <name_of_env> it returns an error
Error: Command '['/home/andrew/coding/pythonCourse/test_folder/tested_works/bin/testing_fails/bin/python3.9', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

after this error it does create the folder but the bin file does not have the activate file and I cannot activate it.

Is the above method not suitable for python 3.9?. Using Conda I have no problems creating virtual environments with 3.9.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 13):

You must install Python 3.9 venv:

```
sudo apt install python3.9-venv
```

Then just do

```
python3.9 -m venv .venv
.venv/bin/python --version
```